# Force compass north to portrait in samsung tablets

Tags: compass-geolocation

I've implented an app that only works in portrait mode. The app have a compass, we know that compass in samsungs tablets (e.g: samsung galaxy tab 2) and mobile devices works different, ones have NORTH (0º) in landscape an others in portrait.

We need to have all in portrait mode, in other words, we want that the NORTH (0º) in PORTRAIT. Anyone have a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Galaxy Note and followed advice on how to determine tablet or phone. This was in another posting but can't remember the link.  The code looks like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    double inches = Math.sqrt((metrics.widthPixels * metrics.widthPixels)
            + (metrics.heightPixels * metrics.heightPixels))
            / metrics.densityDpi;
    // tablets typically larger than 6"" diagonally
    // this is attempt to orient both player and magnetic sensors
    if (inches > 6) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

After doing this, I translated the azimuth setting in the sensorlistener code:

```
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // Note: Not all sensor events will supply both accelerometer and
        // mag-field
        int s = event.sensor.getType();
        switch (s) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            aValues = lowPass(event.values.clone(), aValues);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:

            mValues = lowPass(event.values.clone(), mValues);
            break;
        }

        float[] R = new float[16]; // Rotation Matrix result goes here
        float[] I = new float[9]; // Inclination Matrix result goes here
        float[] oValues = new float[3]; // used for new orientation

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, aValues,
                mValues);
        // if both aValues and mValues are not null success will be true
        // Also returns the Inclination Matrix

        if (success) {
            // Now get the device's orientation from the Rotation and
            // Inclination Matrices
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, oValues);

            // Change Radians to Degrees
            oValues[0] = (360 + (float) Math.toDegrees(oValues[0])) % 360;
            oValues[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(oValues[1]);
            oValues[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(oValues[2]);
            azimuth = oValues[0];//
            y_az = oValues[1];// orientationValues[1];
            z_az = oValues[2];// =

            // test portrait or landscape (different on Tablets)
            int test = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
          // if necessary, azimuth = azimuth+270f  or + 90f %360
            heading.setText("X:" + Math.round(azimuth) + " Y:"
                    + Math.round(y_az) + " Z: " + Math.round(z_az)
                    + " degrees");

        }
    }
```

I ended up letting the tablet stay in landscape mode since most users would orient it that way and North is at the top of the landscape. I hope my rookie code (with plenty of help from others) can help you.